# Flex percent-width not working

Tags: css, apache-flex, flex3

I have a TitleWindow of dimensions 600 X 400. There are a bunch of VBoxes thrown in here that I want to occupy around 80% of the width of the title window in which they are contained.
But they don't seem to register the percent-width property. This is what one of the VBoxes looks like

```
    <mx:VBox  styleName="vboxes">
.vboxes
        {
            cornerRadius:4;
            border-style:solid;
            percent-width:80;
            padding-left:5px;
            padding-right:5px;
            padding-bottom:5px;
            padding-top:5px;
        }
```

The other CSS properties such as border-style and corner-radius seem to register just fine but the percent-width property fails. As a side not, even the width style property fails in this case.

Does anybody know what's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bad news, width/height, percentWidth/percentHeight are not CSS attributes but properties in Flex 3.

Good news, Flex supports custom CSS, which means you can define your own style.  This means you would need to override the `styleChanged` method of your `VBox`, for example:

```
override public function styleChanged(styleProp:String):void
{
    super.styleChanged(styleProp);

    if (styleProp == "percentWidth")
    {
        var val:Number = getStyle("percentWidth") as Number;
        //set percent width logic goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: width/height are CSS properties and they can be set with a percentage value, however, this percentage value is not allowed by Flex

Comment: @ParijatKalia Flex **does not** use standard CSS. As I mentioned in my answer, all of your CSS properties are technically incorrect. What Flex does is use the same syntax as CSS, not the CSS language itself. You should really lookup the Style Properties of each component before blindly using them.

Answer (score 1):

Not every Flex property is available through CSS. In fact, I would say more are not than are. You cannot set dimensions of components via CSS for any component as far as I am aware. You are also using incorrect property names for the ones that are valid.

Please see the Adobe LiveDocs documentation of [VBox styles here.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/containers/VBox.html#commonStyleSummary)